# Laravel 5.6 ajax post without form

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I want to use ajax with selectize to load bdd results onchange. 
I need to use post because I must send data to my url.

My function looks like this :

```
select_etages.load(function(callback) {
        xhr && xhr.abort();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var data = { id:value }
        xhr = $.ajax({
            type: 'post',                
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            data : { bat : value },
            url: 'add/etages',
            success: function(results) {
                callback(results);
            },
            error: function() {
                callback();
            }
        })
    });
```

In my web.php I've got this :

```
Route::post('/lots/add/etages', ['as'   => 'lots.add_post.select', 'uses' => 'Copro\LotController@select2']);
```

And my controller :

```
public function select(Request $request)
{
    return "test";
}
```

But when I tried to use it, I've got an "419 unknown status". I can see that it's a post ajax and my data but I've got no error message :

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   No message

If I change to get it's working but not post.

Anyone know why I can't use post ??

Thank for your help.

Comment: You're missing part of the route path, 'add/etages' should be  'lots/add/etages'

Comment: If I add lots, I've got an 404 error. My current page is /lots/add when I called this script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just rewrite the "select2" name end of the route to "select"?

Comment: Problem with the stack overflow code :) in my code it's select

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove $.ajaxSetup function in callback function. Code might look like this.

```
$(function(){
   $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });


 select_etages.load(function(callback) {
    xhr && xhr.abort();
    var data = { id:value }
    xhr = $.ajax({
        type: 'post',                
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: 'add/etages',
        success: function(results) {
            callback(results);
        },
        error: function() {
            callback();
        }
    })
  });

});
```